# Extending a year range of a popup calendar

Tags: 7, javascript

Good day

Is there a way I can extend a year range of a popup calendar in drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have a *Date* field, the widget you use is the "Pop-up calendar" *and* there is no data in the field yet, you can edit the field and it holds the settings as shown below. Increment the ending year in the field settings

[image]